# ModalBottomSheet con notificaciones

Tags: firebase, flutter, notificaciones

Hola Deseo mostrar un modalBottomSheet al momento de enviar una notificación, por el momento he podido hacerlo con un Snackbar y con una pantalla nueva,

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
PushNotificationService.messagesStream.listen((message) async {
  const storagemensaje = FlutterSecureStorage();
  const options =
      IOSOptions(accessibility: KeychainAccessibility.first_unlock);
  await storagemensaje.write(
      key: 'mensaje', value: message, iOptions: options);


  _navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('message', arguments: message);

  const snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Informativo Intercom'));
}
```

He consultado y me indican que en el init state debo colocar lo siguiente

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container();
        });
  });
```

Pero de los ejemplos al llamar al showModal lo muestran desde un boton al hacer click, alguna idea de como llamarlo

Answer (score 0):

Tu código debería de quedar algo así, esto para que tu bottom se invoque después de que se a construido todo el widget.

Una buena practica seria que esta se pueda invocar desde e servicio que se encarga de escuchar las notificaciones.

Si tienes alguna otra duda puede escribir el comentario.

```
@override 
void initState() {
  PushNotificationServie.messageStream.listen((message) async {
  const storagemensaje = FlutterSecureStorage();
  const  options = IOSOptions(accessibility: KeychainAccessibility.first_unlock);
  await storage mensaje.write( key: 'mensaje', value: message iOptions: options);
  _navigatorKey.curremtState?.pushedNamed('message', arguments: message);
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp){
  // Aqui invocas tu bottomModal
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container();
      });
    });
  }
 }
```